# What was the last version of Xcode shipped with iPhone Simulator 3.0?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, osx-snow-leopard

I installed iPhone Simulator 3.0 on Xcode 3.2.6 on Snow Leopard using a misterious package iPhoneSimulatorSDK3_0.pkg I found on a chinese web page, but the simulator keeps saying "iOS Simulator could not find the SDK. The SDK may need to be reistalled"

So, I need the to install the full version of the mentioned Xcode

Any help is apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iPhone SDK 3.2 Final with Xcode 3.2.2](http://developer.apple.com/ios/download.action?path=/iphone/iphone_sdk_3.2__final/xcode_3.2.2_and_iphone_sdk_3.2_final.dmg) for Snow Leopard (10.6.0) has iOS Simulator 3.0 built-in